# how do i define a date in meteor

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am trying to retrieve the date from which a form was submitted. With the code:

```js
Template.SingleDailylog.helpers({
  date: function(){
    const id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
    if (id) {
        profile = Dailylog.findOne({_id:id});
    }
    if (profile && profile.date) {
        logDate = profile.date;
    }
    if (logDate) {
      return moment(logDate).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    }
    },
```

The date shows up, but in the console it says: Exception in template helper: ReferenceError: logDate is not defined
    at Object.date (http://localhost:3000/app/app.js?hash=b97240050e4c7c8657adb412270a5335856229b7:8546:5)

If I replace 'logDate' with 'name':

```js
Template.SingleDailylog.helpers({
  date: function(){
    const id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
    if (id) {
        profile = Dailylog.findOne({_id:id});
    }
    if (profile && profile.date) {
        name = profile.date;
    }
    if (name) {
      return moment(name).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    }
    },
```

I get: Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format. moment construction falls back to js Date(), which is not reliable across all browsers and versions. Non RFC2822/ISO date formats are discouraged and will be removed in an upcoming major release.

Comment: Show value of `profile.date` (log it to console).

Comment: @Styx When I console.log(logDate), nothing comes up.

Comment: I asked about `profile.date`

Comment: console.log(profile.date) nothing comes up. Unless I am executing this wrong for what you're asking.

Comment: There has to be something, otherwise your `if(logDate)` would be always false.

Comment: For some reason the id is not showing up either when I try to console.log it

Comment: ok it says: Thu Nov 15 2018 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time) but it still has the error: Exception in template helper: TypeError: Cannot read property 'date' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rewrite code like this, in order to avoid using undeclared variables:

```js
Template.SingleDailylog.helpers({
  date: function(){
    const id = FlowRouter.getParam('id');
    if (id) {
      const profile = Dailylog.findOne({_id:id});
      if (profile && profile.date) {
        return moment(profile.date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
      }
    }
  }
})
```